# Calculate a pair of dates connected together

Tags: javascript, date, variables, time, output

The following code outputs me **next Friday** and **next Sunday**. I need to output **next Friday** and **next Sunday after the outputted Friday** ,not just next Sunday. Otherwise If today is Friday or Saturday, It won't work. 
Example: if today is **Friday 05/06** my output will be **Friday 05/13** and **Sunday 05/07** instead of **Sunday 05/15** (that is the output I need).

That is the code I'm using actually. How can I fix it to make it work ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function nextWeekdayDate(date, day_in_week) {
  var ret = new Date(date||new Date());
  ret.setDate(ret.getDate() + (day_in_week - 1 - ret.getDay() + 7) % 7 + 1);
  return ret;
}

var date = new Date();
console.log(nextWeekdayDate(date, 5));

    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#button').click(function(e) {  
        var checkinf = nextWeekdayDate(null, 5);
        var [yyyy, mm, dd] = checkinf.toISOString().split('T')[0].split('-');
        var checkouts = nextWeekdayDate(null, 7);
            var [cyyy, cm, cd] = checkouts.toISOString().split('T')[0].split('-');


             window.open( "https://www.mydynamiclink.com" + variables );

                            });

        });


</script>
```

thanks :)

Comment: Can you put the complete code. Seems like a portion is missing,

Comment: `var [yyyy, mm, dd] = checkinf.toISOString()...` returns UTC date values, is that what you expect? *nextWeekdayDate* creates a date for the local day, UTC might be one day before or after depending on the host timezone setting and time of day that the code is run.

Comment: The dates in the OP are confusing, e.g. " Friday 05/06" seems to mean Friday 5 June but "Friday 05/13" seems to mean 13 May, which was a Wednesday, and "Sunday 05/15" seems to mean Friday 15 May. Far better to always use the month name or abbreviation to avoid ambiguity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assignment:

```
var checkouts = nextWeekdayDate(null, 7);
```

gets the next Sunday after today. What you want is the Sunday after *checkinf*, so pass it in the call. Also, the day number for Sunday is 0:

```
var checkouts = nextWeekdayDate(checkinf, 0);
```

```js
function nextWeekdayDate(date, day_in_week) {
  var ret = new Date(date || new Date());
  ret.setDate(ret.getDate() + (day_in_week - 1 - ret.getDay() + 7) % 7 + 1);
  return ret;
}


let nextFriday = nextWeekdayDate(null, 5);
let followingSunday = nextWeekdayDate(nextFriday, 0);

console.log('Next Friday     : ' +  nextFriday.toDateString() +
  '\nFollowing Sunday: ' + followingSunday.toDateString());
```

Answer (score 1):

I think for the `checkouts`, you can simply increase the `checkinf` by two days if your  `checkinf` are correctly outputted.

What I mean is this:
 Instead of `var checkouts = nextWeekdayDate(null, 7);`

Your should do this:

`var checkouts = checkinf.setDate(checkinf.getDay() + 2);` //For the next sunday